# Seleccionar Checkbox que ya estan en la base de datos en un formulario

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo un formulario que a la hora de editar aparece los datos de que se ingresaron en automatico en caso de querer actualizarlos excepto que no aparecen los checkbox marcados que se ingresaron me gustaria saber ¿Como le hago?

**(En donde dice **inventario** son los checkbox que se insertaron)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**(Este es el formulario para editar)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**(Este es todo el codigo de mi pagina donde esta el formulario de editar)**

```
    <?php include '../includes/db.php';

?>


<div id="entradas<?php echo $row['folio']?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
       

<div class="modal-dialog"> 
               <div class="modal-content modal-md"> 
                  <div class="modal-header"> 
                     <center><h4 class="modal-title" id='head'>
                     Editar orden de entrada
                     </h4> </center>
                     <div id="retCode"></div>
                  </div> 
                       <form method="POST" id='update_entradas'  action="../forms/update_forms.php?action=entradas" > 
 <div class="modal-body">
   
    <div class="form-horizontal">

    
          <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Inventario:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ANTENA">ANTENA <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESPEJO LATERAL">ESPEJO LATERAL <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EMBLEMAS">EMBLEMAS <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPONES RUEDAS(4)">TAPONES RUEDAS(4) <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="MOLDURAS">MOLDURAS COMPLETAS<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPÓN DE GASOLINA">TAPÓN DE GASOLINA<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN">LLANATA DE REFACCIÓN<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="RADIO/TIPO">RADIO/TIPO<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ENCENDEDOR">ENCENDEDOR<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPETES">TAPETES<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="BOCINA DE CLAXÓN">BOCINA DE CLAXON<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA">GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EXTINTOR">EXTINTOR<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE GASOLINA">TARJETA DE GASOLINA<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GATO">GATO<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLAVE DE RUEDAS">LLAVE DE RUEDAS<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS">ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD">TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN">CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN">TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN<br>  
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btn_sub"><i class="fa fa-save "></i> Actualizar</button>
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-close"></i>Cerrar</button>
            </form>
                     </div>
                     </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
```

**(El ejemplo de lo que busco)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería ideal manejar los ítems con IDs y no con strings, pero ya que está así: deberías convertir el string a un array con `explode()`, algo como `$inventario_arrray = explode(",", $Inventario)` Luego debes comprobar si el valor del elemento checkbox del formulario existe dentro de $inventario_arrray, puede hacerese con `in_array()`, con lo cual puedes poner una condición en cada elemento o, mejor, crear un array de los elementos, iterarlos para generar los checkbox y al mismo tiempo chequear si el valor existe.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme habra posibilidad de que me ayudes el como puedo hacer todo lo que me dijiste por favor

Answer (score 0):

Vas a necesitar:

1. Por un lado un array con todos los valores posibles, estén o no en la columna `inventario` de la fila que estés leyendo
2. Obtener los valores de la columna y crear un array a partir de ellos usando [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)
3. Verificar con [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) si cada dato de ese array existe para entonces crear ese checkbox con estatus `checked`.

El código sería así:

```
/*
    Asumimos que la lista viene en
    la columna llamada inventario
    la obtenemos desde $row y hacemos explode
    Para prevenir posibles espacios en blanco
    aplicaremos además  trim a cada elemento del array
    mediante el uso de array_map
    Los espacios en blanco pueden fastidiar este tipo de diseño
    por eso, entre otras cosas, 
    es mejor diseñar basándose en índices numéricos
*/

$dbInventary= array_map('trim', explode(',', $row['inventario']));

/*
    Esta es una plantilla para crear los input
    con una mayor claridad
*/

$input='<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="%s" %s/>%s<br>';

foreach($allInventary as $item) {
    /*
        Si $item está en $dbInventary el valor
        de la variable $checked será checked
        de lo contrario será un valor en blanco
        que no produce ningún efecto.
        NÓTESE el uso de trim() para limpiar posibles espacios en blanco
        uno de los grandes peligros en este tipo de diseños son los espacios en blanco ...
        Luego con printf reemplazamos cada cosa en la plantilla
    */
    $checked=in_array($item,$dbInventary) ? "checked" : "";    
    printf($input,$item,$checked,$item);
}
```

---

En una prueba hipotética, imaginemos una columna `inventario` con estos valores:

```
$row['inventario']='ANTENA,ESPEJO LATERAL,EMBLEMAS,TAPONES RUEDAS(4),MOLDURAS,ENCENDEDOR,TAPETES,TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD,CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN';
```

El código de más arriba creará los `input` así:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ANTENA" checked/>ANTENA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESPEJO LATERAL" checked/>ESPEJO LATERAL<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EMBLEMAS" checked/>EMBLEMAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPONES RUEDAS(4)" checked/>TAPONES RUEDAS(4)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="MOLDURAS" checked/>MOLDURAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPÓN DE GASOLINA" />TAPÓN DE GASOLINA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN" />LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="RADIO/TIPO" />RADIO/TIPO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ENCENDEDOR" checked/>ENCENDEDOR<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPETES" checked/>TAPETES<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="BOCINA DE CLAXÓN" />BOCINA DE CLAXÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA" />GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EXTINTOR" />EXTINTOR<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE GASOLINA" />TARJETA DE GASOLINA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GATO" />GATO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLAVE DE RUEDAS" />LLAVE DE RUEDAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS" />ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD" checked/>TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN" checked/>CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN" />TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN<br>
```

Aquí lo tenemos en un snippet:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ANTENA" checked/>ANTENA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESPEJO LATERAL" checked/>ESPEJO LATERAL<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EMBLEMAS" checked/>EMBLEMAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPONES RUEDAS(4)" checked/>TAPONES RUEDAS(4)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="MOLDURAS" checked/>MOLDURAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPÓN DE GASOLINA" />TAPÓN DE GASOLINA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN" />LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="RADIO/TIPO" />RADIO/TIPO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ENCENDEDOR" checked/>ENCENDEDOR<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPETES" checked/>TAPETES<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="BOCINA DE CLAXÓN" />BOCINA DE CLAXÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA" />GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EXTINTOR" />EXTINTOR<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE GASOLINA" />TARJETA DE GASOLINA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GATO" />GATO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLAVE DE RUEDAS" />LLAVE DE RUEDAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS" />ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD" checked/>TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN" checked/>CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN" />TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN<br>
```

### Post-Data

Como ya te comentaron en la pregunta, no es buena idea guardar listas de esta manera en la base de datos. Te expones a errores, como que escriban mal un nombre, que dejen espacios en blanco, que escriban en mayúscula / minúscula, etc. Aparte de eso, otro tipo de consultas serán complicadas, por ejemplo, saber cuántas ocurrencias de `ANTENA` hay en inventario, o en qué inventario hay `ANTENA` y no hay `EMBLEMAS` o cosas así.